# libGDX fonts: using multiple colors for a simple character

Tags: fonts, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

Whenever I dealt with fonts in libGDX so far, I used the [FreeTypeFontGenerator](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-freetype/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeTypeFontGenerator.java) to create a BitmapFont out of a `.ttf`-File. Now my problem is the following: I want a font that supports not just one, but multiple colours for each character. For example, I'd like to use a font like [this one](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Londrina+Outline) and to choose both a color for the character itself and for its outline. How can I do that? Do I have to create my own BitmapFont file, and if so, how? Or is there any better / easier way?

Comment: Do you need only a few colors or a wide range of them?

Comment: a few colors will do fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using the Hiero tool (included in the `gdx-tools` package) to generate the fonts. It supports adding/editing things like outlines and color with a few clicks, but it doesn't work in runtime - you have to pre-render the fonts. This means that you'll be scaling them when drawing in the game, which can cause some ugly artifacts. You could also pre-render a few different sizes and choose the most appropriate one when running. You'd end up with quite a few font files though, as you'd need a file for each combination of a size and a color scheme.

If that's too uncomfortable, I suppose you could try looking at the Hiero and FreeTypeFontGenerator source codes to create a generator that supports such effects *and* runtime generation, but I'd guess that wouldn't be a simple task.